# How can I extract the string in a Google Sheets cell when the values are separated by a delimiter?

Tags: google-sheets, delimiter

How would I write a formula in Google Sheets that extracts the following:

I want to grab the 3rd string (0 being first in this example) from column M below, and store that string in column A.

```
    [M2] 2872_TX_USA_Event_Farming Convention_CST_Planned                    
    [M3] 4980_BC_CAN_Campaign_Politics_PST_Active
```

I want column A to look like this:

```
    [A2] Event 
    [A3] Campaign
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try in A2 and copied down:

```
=regexreplace(mid(M2,13,50),"_.+",)
```

OR

```
=index(split(M2,"_"),1,4)
```